# Does Gradle provide a way to add a task without including it in the build script?

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

I have a few custom Gradle tasks I've created perform analysis on the build, which I'll make use of when doing certain types changes (e.g. viewing changes in included dependencies as I upgrade library versions).  These are tasks for my own benefit, and not something I want committed to source control.  Therefore, I ideally want them specified externally to `build.gradle` and included in a manner that does not require changing any of the committed build files.  Otherwise, the custom tasks will undoubtably be accidentally included in a commit and will need to be backed out later.

To make it concrete, here's a simplified version of a task which prints all compile-time dependencies:

```groovy
task dependencyList {
    doLast {
        println "Compile dependencies:"
        def selectedDeps = project.configurations.compileClasspath.incoming.resolutionResult.allDependencies.collect { dep ->
            "${dep.selected}"
        }
        selectedDeps.unique().sort().each { println it }
    }
}
```

How can I execute this task against my Gradle build without making any changes to `build.groovy` or other files that would normally be committed to source control with the project?

Comment: Check out [initialization scrips](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) in the Gradle documentation!

Comment: @LukasKörfer Thanks for the pointer! I expanded this into a full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68233285/1108305

Answer (score 3):

An [initialization script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html) can be used for this purpose, adding the custom task to the project(s) in the build:

```groovy
allprojects {
    task dependencyList {
        doLast {
            println "Compile dependencies:"
            def selectedDeps = project.configurations.compileClasspath.incoming.resolutionResult.allDependencies.collect { dep ->
                "${dep.selected}"
            }
            selectedDeps.unique().sort().each { println it }
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle provides a number of ways to use the initialization script, which are listed in the feature's [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script):

> - Specify a file on the command line. The command line option is `-I` or `--init-script` followed by the path to the script. [...]
> - Put a file called `init.gradle` (or `init.gradle.kts` for Kotlin) in the `USER_HOME/.gradle/` directory.
> - Put a file that ends with `.gradle` (or `.init.gradle.kts` for Kotlin) in the `USER_HOME/.gradle/init.d/` directory.
> - Put a file that ends with `.gradle` (or `.init.gradle.kts` for Kotlin) in the `GRADLE_HOME/init.d/` directory, in the Gradle distribution. [...]

For a task which should only be present in the build on demand, the `--init-script` command line option would be the option to use.

```
gradle --init-script /path/to/dependency-list.gradle dependencyList
```

Comment: Thanks to [Lukas Körfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3950370/lukas-körfer) for suggesting this approach in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229494/#comment120591841_68229494)